# Grep command behaving weirdly in terminal emulation

Tags: c, linux, shell, pipe

I wrote a program that aims to simulate the terminal, more specifically, unnamed pipes. For example, I can simulate the terminal command cat file | grep 'aa' 
using the command

./myterminal cat file - grep 'aa'

(I separate the arguments with - instead of |). And it works perfectly. However, if I try to use the command 
./myterminal cat file - grep 'aa' - grep 'bb'

I get the error messege:

Usage: aa [OPTION] ... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'aa--help' for more information.

So obviously something is wrong. When I try the command
./myterminal cat file - grep 'aa' 'file' - grep 'bb' 'file'

The correct line from the file is printed -- however, so is the error message. What is happening here? Clearly something is wrong with my program, I just dont understand what. The program itself is so simple I'm not sure what's going wrong here.

The code itself is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void np_exec(char* cmd, char** argv)
{
int fd[2];

while(*(++argv) != NULL)
{
    pipe(fd);

    int pid = fork(); //parent executes
    if(pid < 0)
    {
        printf("Error forking");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(pid != 0) // parent
    {
        dup2(fd[1],1);
        close(fd[0]);   

        if (execvp(cmd, argv) == -1)
        {
            perror("execvp failed");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dup2(fd[0],0);  
        close(fd[1]);
    }
}
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
assert(strcmp(argv[argc-1], "-"));

int i;
for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
    if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-")) 
    {
        argv[i] = NULL;
        np_exec(argv[1], &argv[1]);
        argv = &argv[i];
        argc -= i;
        i = 0;
    }
}

char* args[argc];
args[argc-1] = NULL;

for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
    args[i-1] = argv[i];
}

if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1)
    perror("execvp failed");

return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know where I'm wrong?

Comment: Why in the world is this tagged bash? You're not using bash at all. "Joe A's shell" is certainly not bash. (Not just picking on you, btw -- anyone asking about csh or ksh or zsh and tagging their question bash would be every bit as off-base).

Comment: ...back towards topic, use `strace -f -e execve ./myterminal cat file - grep 'aa' - grep 'bb'`, and see what arguments your code is passing around.

Comment: Actually -- `Usage: aa` makes at least one problem obvious; you're passing `argv[1]` in the position where `argv[0]` needs to be.

Comment: You're the man Charles! Its fixed!